# is there anyway to find whether elements in list are increasing followed by a decreasing digit?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

i need to find a list is True or False  in which numbers are in  increasing order followed by decreasing order.

or numbers in decreasing order followed by increasing order.
You can assume that consecutive numbers in the input sequence are always different from each other.

i tried the below code but unable get the appropriate return value i.e(True/False)
can someone give give any suggestion on how to improve my code?

```
def hillvalley(A): 

    return (all(A[i] <= A[i + 1] for i in range(len(A) - 1)) or
        all(A[i] >= A[i + 1] for i in range(len(A) - 1))) 

hillvalley([1,2,3,5,4,3,2,1])
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO, please include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) including example inputs and expected outputs. In which tests is it failing? What do you expect and what is actually happening?

Answer (score 1):

Works by finding index of maximum and minimum.

For increasing, followed by decreasing checks that values up to index of max is increasing, then decreasing afterward.

For decreasing, followed by increasing checks that values up to index of min is decreasing, then increasing afterward.

Able to handle plateaus.

**Code**

```
def hillvalley(A):
  # Check increasing followed by decreasing
  index, _ = max(enumerate(A), key=lambda v: v[1])
  if all(A[i]<=A[i+1] for i in range(index)) and \
    all(A[i]>=A[i+1] for i in range(index, len(A)-1)):
    return True

  # Check decreasing followed by increasing
  index, _ = min(enumerate(A), key=lambda v: v[1])
  if all(A[i]>=A[i+1] for i in range(index)) and \
    all(A[i]<=A[i+1] for i in range(index, len(A)-1)):
    return True

  return False
```

**Test**

```
for t in [[1,2,3,5,4,3,2,1], [4,3,2,1,1,2,3,5], [1,2,1,5,4,3,2,1]]:
  print(f'{t} -> {hillvalley(t)}')
```

**Output**

```
[1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1] -> True
[4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5] -> True
[1, 2, 1, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1] -> False
```

Answer (score 0):

This assumes there are no "plateaus" (or, cases where two consecutive elements are equal). If you want to account for that, I'll leave it as an exercise for you to modify this code accordingly.

```
def hillvalley(A):
    # determine which direction we're going
    orig_direction = (A[1] > A[0])
    # make a flag for when we switch directions (hill-to-valley, or valley-to-hill)
    switched_direction = orig_direction
    # do comparisons to the last element:
    last = A[1]
    for e in A[2:]:
        # determine our current direction
        current_direction = (e > last)
        # are we still moving the same direction as we were last time?
        if current_direction != switched_direction:
            # if not, then determine how many times we're changing direction
            if switched_direction == orig_direction:
                # this is the first time we're changing direction, so it's fine
                switched_direction = current_direction
            else:
                # this is the second time, which means it fails the test
                return False
        last = e
    # if we don't return during any of that, then it passes the test
    return True
```

```
>>> hillvalley([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1])
True
>>> hillvalley([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 3])
False
```